# React Native - List View doesn't scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new in React so i work on a mini project of mine with a simple list. This is the code :

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <ToolbarAndroid style={styles.toolbar}
               title={"Hello React"}
               titleColor={'#000000'}/>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderMovie}
            style={styles.listView}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Also the style code:

```
 listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not working because you forgot to set the size of the **View**. Add flex:1 and it will work properly

styles

```
listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
},
container: {
    flex: 1
}
```

render

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ToolbarAndroid style={styles.toolbar}
               title={"Hello React"}
               titleColor={'#000000'}/>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderMovie}
            style={styles.listView}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

[Example with the problem fixed (iOS version)](https://rnplay.org/apps/v6ZR_g)